# List of pairs into pair of Lists Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, tuples, list-comprehension

Basically I have this exercise:
Using list comprehensions, write a polymorphic function:

```
split :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
```

which transforms a list of pairs (of any types) into a pair of lists. For example,

```
split [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')] = ([1, 2, 3], "abc")
```

This was the way I wrote the function but it is not working:

```
split :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
split listOfPairs = (([a | a <- listOfPairs]), ([b | b <- listOfPairs]))
```

Can someone please explain why my solution doesn't work? Thank you!

Comment: `let ls = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')] in ([ n | (n,m) <- ls] , [ c | (d,c) <- ls ])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list comprehension like:

```
[a | a <- listOfPairs]
```

is actually nothing more than an *identity operation* for lists. It will yield the same list as the one you provide, since you basically iterate over `listOfPairs`, and for each iteration, you yield the element `a`.

Haskell does not perform *implicit* conversions, so it does *not* derive from the types that `a` in your `a <- listOfPairs` then only can be the first element. Even if that was possible, it was probably *not* a good idea anyway, since it would make the language more "unstable" in the sense that a small change in the types, could have significant impact in the semantics.

In order to obtain the first element of a tuple, you need to use *pattern matching*, like:

```
[a | (a, _) <- listOfPairs]
```

here we thus pattern match the first element of the tuple with `a`, and for the second one, we thus use:

```
[b | (_, b) <- listOfPairs]
```

We can thus impelement this as:

```
split:: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
split listOfPairs = ([a | (a, _) <- listOfPairs], [b | (_, b) <- listOfPairs])
```

Or we can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map), [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) and [**`snd :: (a, b) -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd):

```
split:: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
split listOfPairs = (map fst listOfPairs, map snd listOfPairs)
```

But the above still has a problem: here we iterate twice *independently* over the same list. We can omit that by using recursion, like:

```
split:: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
split [] = []
split ((a, b):xs) = (a:as, b:bs)
    where (as, bs) = split xs
```

or we can use a `foldr` function:

```
split :: Foldable f => f (a,b) -> ([a],[b])
split = foldr (\(a,b) (as,bs) -> (a:as,b:bs)) ([],[])
```

There is already a Haskell function that does exactly what you want: [**`unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unzip), with the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#unzip).

Comment: Once again, thank you very much for the great explanation!

Comment: It seems to me that OP hoped that the pattern-matching could be done at the type level, so to speak, by using the names `a` and `b` to match against the two parts of the `(a, b)` tuples. It might be worth a quick mention of why that doesn't work.

Comment: @amalloy: ah, yes, that was probably where the OP was after. I hope the extra paragraph makes it clear.